# Use SAPI 4 voices with SAPI 5 in Microsoft Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, sapi, speech-synthesis, synthesize

I've been trying to use SAPI 4 voices with Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 which seems to be only be able to use SAPI 5. I am trying to get a mere Text-To-Speech working.

When I run a code to list the installed voices it only shows me the default Anna voice. However, [as seen here](http://puu.sh/hw5CC/5863596518.png) in another program called "Text To Wav" which oddly seems to be able to also use the SAPI 4 voices, it lists, as you can see, way more than just Anna.

I am running on a 64 bit Windows 7 system.

So, my question is:

Is there a way to make Visual Studio 2013 use SAPI 4?
As other programs, such as the [Text To Wav program](http://puu.sh/hw5GO/f4bb46844b.png), are able to use SAPI 4 voices, why can't I in Microsoft Visual Studio?

Answer (score -1):

SAPI 4 is an *extremely* old library.  It's not shipped with any Windows OS, and it's long out of support, *and* it doesn't support 64 bit programs.

So - it's *really* not recommended to use SAPI 4, and it's a *really* bad idea to continue down this path.